# windows phone 7 Error ON:System.Net

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I have built a windows phone 7 library and I created a test project at the same time.  When I run the tests, I get the following error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly“System.Net, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e”

But the reference was already in the project.  This is the code in the class:

```
public class SinaApiService
{

    public string userName;
    public string passWord;
    private string secertKey;

    public string SecertKey
    {
        get { return secertKey; }
        set { secertKey = value; }
    }

    private bool needInitWebClient = true;
    public static System.Net.WebClient wc;

    public void InitSinaApiService(string userName, string passWord, string secretKey)
    {
        if (needInitWebClient)
        {
            this.userName = userName;
            this.passWord = passWord;
            this.SecertKey = secertKey;
            needInitWebClient = false;
            wc = new WebClient();
            wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, passWord);
            wc.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic" + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userName + ":" + passWord));
        }
        else
        { }
    }
}
```

When i do the unit test like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    WPSina.SinaApiService wc = new WPSina.SinaApiService();
    wc.InitSinaApiService("hello@gmail.com", "XXXXX", "123456"); ;
    wc.public_timeline();
    object obj = WPSina.SinaApiService.public_timeline_context;
    Assert.AreNotEqual(null,obj.ToString());
}
```

Can anybody help to solve it?

Thanks!!

Comment: i am sorry,my English is poor,so it is a little for me to ask question with the correct meaning~I

Comment: I don't know much about phone development, so this is just a guess but don't you build phone apps against the Compact version of the framework? My guess is your building against the wrong version of .Net.

Comment: ok,thanks,i will try other .NET frame

Comment: Fixed up the question a bit.  I am having the same issue.  Did trying other versions fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Does the file exists?
It should be here: **c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone\System.Net.dll**

If it is not present (on x86 OS look into your c:\Program Files... folder) try uninstalling and installing the WPDT again.